# Difference between initContainers and containers in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, containers

I noticed in a deployment file there are two fields for containers like `initContainers` and `containers` and looks confusing to me and I search through the internet but can't understand. Could anyone please tell me the difference between `initContainers` and `containers` and how we use them together?

For example

```
  containers:
  - name: php
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dir
      mountPath: /dir
  initContainers:
  - name: install
    image: busybox
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dir
      mountPath: /dir
    command:
    - wget
    - "-O"
    - "/dir/index.php"
    - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/videofalls/demo/master/index.php
```

It's really appreciable and thanks in advance!!

Comment: I did an Internet search for the title of your question: "Difference between initContainers and containers in Kubernetes", and the first result is the official Kubernetes docs on initContainers: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/. The first two sections in that doc are "Understanding init containers" and "Differences from regular containers". Then there is the section on "Using init containers" with an "Examples" section that shows an example Deployment using both init containers and regular containers.

Comment: Your current question is very generic. What specifically would you like to know that isn't already answered in the official docs?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

About [Containers:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/)

> Containers are a technology for packaging the (compiled) code for an application along with the dependencies it needs at run time. Each container that you run is repeatable; the standardization from having dependencies included means that you get the same behavior wherever you run it.

About [InitContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/):

> Init containers are exactly like regular containers, except:
>
> - Init containers always run to completion before the container execution.
> - Each initContainer **must complete successfully before the next one starts**.
> - If a Pod’s init container fails, Kubernetes **repeatedly restarts the Pod** until the init container succeeds. However, if the Pod has a  `restartPolicy`  of Never, Kubernetes does not restart the Pod.

Summarizing:
`Containers` hosts your dockerized applications, `initContainer` run tasks that are required to run **before** the main Container execution.

---

One simple example is the code you provided:

- You created a container with a php server, but you want the content of `index.html` to be always updated, without having to change the pod manifest itself.
- So you added a `initContainer` to fetch the updated `index.php` and add to the container.
- I've fixed your yaml with the `volume` parameters to add the `emptyDir` that will hold the downloaded file and changing the `mountPath` to the default html folder `/var/www/html`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: php-updated
spec:
  containers:
  - name: php
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dir
      mountPath: /var/www/html/
  initContainers:
  - name: install
    image: busybox
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dir
      mountPath: /var/www/html/
    command:
    - wget
    - "-O"
    - "/var/www/html/index.php"
    - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/videofalls/demo/master/index.php
  volumes:
  - name: dir
    emptyDir: {}
```

**POC:**

```
$ kubectl apply -f php.yaml 
pod/php-updated created

$ kubectl get pod
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
php-updated   1/1     Running   0          3s

$ kubectl exec -it php-updated -- /bin/bash
root@php-updated:/var/www/html# cat index.php 
<?php 
echo 'Demo Test';
```

- As you can see the `initContainer` ran before the pod, downloaded the file to the mounted volume that is shared with the PHP server `Container`.

**NOTE:** The above webserver is not fully functional because the full `php-fpm`  deployment is a little more complex, and it's not the core of this question, so I'll leave this tutorial for it: [PHP-FPM, Nginx, Kubernetes, and Docker](https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/php-fpm-nginx-kubernetes.html)

One could argue that `index.html` is not a critical file for Pod initialization, and could be replaced during pod execution using `Command` so I'll leave here an answer I gave for persistently changing `resolv.conf` before pod initialization even after pod restart: [DNS Config is Skipped in GKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60508061/dnsconfig-is-skipped-in-gke).

---

Another great usage of `initContainer` is to make a pod wait for another resource in the cluster to be ready before initializing.

- Here is a pod with a `initContainer` called `init-mydb` that waits and watched for a service called `mydb` to be on `running` state before allowing the container `myapp-container` start, imagine `myapp-container` is an app that requires the database connection before execution, otherwise it would fail repeatedly.

**Reproduction:**

- here is the manifest `my-app.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: my-app
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-app
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: myapp-container
        image: busybox:1.28
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
      initContainers:
      - name: init-mydb
        image: busybox:1.28
        command: ['sh', '-c', "until nslookup mydb.$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace).svc.cluster.local; do echo waiting for mydb; sleep 2; done"]
```

- Now let's apply it see the status of the deployment:

```
$ kubectl apply -f my-app.yaml 
deployment.apps/my-app created

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                      READY   STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
my-app-6b4fb4958f-44ds7   0/1     Init:0/1   0          4s
my-app-6b4fb4958f-s7wmr   0/1     Init:0/1   0          4s
```

- The pods are hold on `Init:0/1` status waiting for the completion of the init container.
- Now let's create the service which the `initContainer` is waiting to be `running` before completing his task:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mydb
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 9377
```

- We will apply it and monitor the changes in the pods:

```
$ kubectl apply -f mydb-svc.yaml 
service/mydb created

$ kubectl get pods -w
NAME                      READY   STATUS     RESTARTS   AGE
my-app-6b4fb4958f-44ds7   0/1     Init:0/1   0          91s
my-app-6b4fb4958f-s7wmr   0/1     Init:0/1   0          91s
my-app-6b4fb4958f-s7wmr   0/1     PodInitializing   0          93s
my-app-6b4fb4958f-44ds7   0/1     PodInitializing   0          94s
my-app-6b4fb4958f-s7wmr   1/1     Running           0          94s
my-app-6b4fb4958f-44ds7   1/1     Running           0          95s
^C
$ kubectl get all
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/my-app-6b4fb4958f-44ds7   1/1     Running   0          99s
pod/my-app-6b4fb4958f-s7wmr   1/1     Running   0          99s

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/mydb         ClusterIP   10.100.106.67   <none>        80/TCP    14s

NAME                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/my-app   2/2     2            2           99s

NAME                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/my-app-6b4fb4958f   2         2         2       99s
```

---

- Finally I'll leave you a few more examples on how to use `InitContainers`:

  - [Kubernetes.io InitContainer Examples](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#examples)
  - [A Spring-boot Use Case with Kubernetes](https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/configuration-management-kubernetes-spring-boot/)
  - [Kubernetes.io Configure a Pod Initialization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/)
  - [The InitContainer Pattern](https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-patterns-the-init-container-pattern)

If you have any questions let me know in the comments!

Comment: Could you please see this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61716695/how-to-run-a-simple-php-hello-world-application-using-kubernetes @willrof

Answer (score 5):

`Init Containers`  run before the main container runs. Normally init containers are used to ensure the server environment is ready for your application to start to run.

Go through the detailed [official document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/?spm=a2c41.12820943.0.0.30365d45MEKjSb#what-can-init-containers-be-used-for) for better understanding