# The data is not being shared across containers

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create two containers within a pod with one container being an init container. The job of the init container is to download a jar and make it available for the app container. I am able to create everything and the logs look good but when i check, i do not see the jar in my app container. Below is my deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-service-test
  labels:
    app: web-service-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web-service-test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web-service-test
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: shared-data
        emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: web-service-test
        image: some image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-data
          mountPath: /tmp/jar
      initContainers:
      - name: init-container
        image: busybox
        volumeMounts:
        - name: shared-data
          mountPath: /jdbc-jar
        command:
        - wget
        - "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc/ojdbc8/19.3.0.0/ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar"
```

Comment: Can you include in your question the commands you're using to check for the presence of the downloaded file in your `web-service-test` container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following block of code to your init container section:

```
command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
args: ["wget -O /jdbc-jar/ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc/ojdbc8/19.3.0.0/ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar"]
```

The  `command ["/bin/sh", "-c"]`  says "run a shell, and execute the following instructions". The args are then passed as commands to the shell. In shell scripting a semicolon separates commands. In the `wget` command I have added the -O flag to download the jar from the specified url and save it as `/jdbc-jar/ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar` .
To check if jar is persistent in container. Simply execute command:

```
$ kubectl exec -it web-service-test -- /bin/bash
```

Then go to folder   `/jdbc-jar` ( `$ cd jdbc-jar` ) and list files in it (`$ ls -al`). You should see your jar there.

See examples: [commands-in-containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887194/how-to-set-multiple-commands-in-one-yaml-file-with-kubernetes), [initcontainers-running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61858409/difference-between-initcontainers-and-containers-in-kubernetes).

Answer (score 2):

You need to save jar in the `/jdbc-jar` folder

try updating your yaml to following

```
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c", "wget -O /pod-data/ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc/ojdbc8/19.3.0.0/ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar"]
```